# Java Regex: How to realize: [A-Z][a-z]* followed either by ((" " (blank) or "-") and [A-Z][a-z]* again) (x-times) or the end of this string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a regex for something like that:

`[A-Z][a-z]*` followed either by ((" " (blank) or "-") and [A-Z][a-z]* again) (x-times) or the end of this string.

Something like:

```
"Aaaa-Aaa Aaaa-Aaaa" should work.  
"aA aaa" shouldn't work.  
"Ann Aaa " shoudln't work.
```

I don't understand why I get this results ([f][f] = [A-Z][a-z]):

```
String s = "f f";
  System.out.println(s.matches("f([ -][^$]|$)+")); (TRUE)

String s = "ff ff";
  System.out.println(s.matches("[f][f]([ -][^$]|$)+")); (FALSE)

String s = "ff ff";
  System.out.println(s.matches("([f][f]([ -][^$]|$))+")); (FALSE)

String s = "ff ff";
  System.out.println(s.matches("(([f][f])([ -][^$]|$))+")); (FALSE)
```

Comment: Where is `x`? `*` makes everything optional.

Comment: x isnt part of this. I just tried to explain the regex in words.  [A-Z][a-z]* " " or "-" [A-Z][a-z]* can be repeated multiple times.

Comment: What do you think `[^$]` does?

Comment: I think that means "not end of string"

Comment: No `[..]` is character class so `$` us treated as character. In this case `[^$]` simply means not-`$` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for something like

```
[A-Z][a-z]*($|([- ][A-Z][a-z]*){n})
```

Comment: Simply replace `n` with value you are looking for. Also I am not sure if you even need `$` but you would need to explain why you want it in your regex.

Comment: Yeah, thank u very much. I just couldn't accept this answer jet.. This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[^$] doesn't mean what you think it does. The 'ff' variants don't match, simply because of missing a few parenthesis.

You could try `([f][f]([ -]|$))+`, or even `(ff([ -]|$))+`, or `([a-zA-Z]{2}([ -]|$))+`

http://regexpal.com/ is your friend